# jquery datatable custom sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery datatable plugin, I have a column where I have multiple values of "Yes" and multiple values of "No"
My problem is this function below sorts alphabetically.
my question is  how do I change the function so it shows Yes first then No on my table.
any help would greatly appreciated.

```
$('#datatbl').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 6, "asc" ]]
});
```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do:

```
$('#datatbl').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 6, "desc" ]] 
});
```

Comment: Surely if he wants Yes then No, it should be descending?